# nginx configuration error for websocket configuration

Tags: reactjs, nginx

My Nginx config file is as below,
My application is using web socket and i need to configure it using nginx, on my local dev machine, everything works fine with node , but i do not have idea regarding how can i configure socket in nginx, i tired as below but getting error.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    #sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  0;
    #gzip  on;

    upstream project1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:4001;
        }
    server {
            server_name dev.project1.net;
            root /usr/local/evp/project1/web/dist/;

                location /api/ {
                               proxy_pass http://project1;
                               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                               add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
                             }
                 location /ws{
                               proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001/ws;
                         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                         add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
                         }

               location /report/ { alias /home/admin/_var/QCACHE/; }
               location / {try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?route=$uri&$args;}

             error_page 404 /usr/local/evp/project1/web/dist/index.html;
               location = /404.html {}
               error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
               location = /50x.html {}

             listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
             listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
             ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.project1.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
             ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.project1.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
             #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
             #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
          }

        server {
                 if ($host = dev.project1.net) {
                 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
                 } # managed by Certbot
                    listen 80;
                    listen [::]:80;
                server_name dev.project1.net;
                return 404; # managed by Certbot
              }
}
```

My projects setupProxy.js is as below,

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:4001' }));
  app.use(proxy('/socket', { target: 'http://localhost:4001', ws: true }));
};
```

But when, I am trying to access https://dev.project1.net/, I am getting error as below,
dev.project1.net says
ERROR CONNECTING TO WEBSOCKET:
wss://dev.project1.net/socket

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution at below link,
https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

modified /socket block as ,

```
 location /socket{
                               proxy_pass http://project1;
                                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                                   add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
                       proxy_http_version 1.1;
                           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                       proxy_set_header Host $host;
                         }
```

Important line is : proxy_set_header Host $host;